# AJAX category page navigation and going back from product page (Magento 1.9.3)

Tags: ajax, navigation

I'm wondering if this is even possible to do:
I have ajax category pages navigation and url stays the same no matter what page you are on. Is it possible to redirect to that certain page where the product was chosen and when clicking browser "back" button on product page.

For example I choose product on the 4th page and click back, and I will be on that 4th page again? I know i could do this when there is no ajax navigation, but can I combine these two?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using a 3rd party module to get the Ajax category page function, as I don't believe Magento has this by default.  Unless there is a configuration available on that module, you will need to extend the module to get this function.

Another option is to use a different 3rd party module for category navigation.  I use Amasty's "Improved Layered Navigation" module and it has the function you are looking for out of the box.

https://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation.html